# place variable value into a specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi just a quick easy one, im not very experienced with scripts in sheets. I have my variables set up but i would just like to return the variable to a specific cell when the script is ran. I marked as a comment in the script below what i would like from it.
Thanks!

```html
// Menu for testing script
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Record value')
      .addItem('Record now','tester')
      .addToUi();
}

function tester() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Matt");
   var value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L3').getValue();
    // i would like to append "value1" to to cell "B3" here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setValue(value)` to append a value into a cell, keeping the original value intact:

If the destination sheet is the active sheet:

```
var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3");
var original = dest.getValue();
dest.setValue(original+value1);
```

If the destination sheet is the named one:

```
var dest = sheet.getRange("B3");
var original = dest.getValue();
dest.setValue(original+value1);
```

References:

[setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)